# Secret Detection Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, secret-key, jenkins-github-plugin

I have my pipeline on jenkins and source code mangement is on gitlab.

Can I trigger the secret detection on the gitlab from Jenkins, since the pipeline is on jenkins and secret detection is enabled for gitlab pipelines? And how could it be done?